# When a File Explorer window has a directory opened, and I try to delete this dir, there is some sort of file permission error. What to do?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, php

1. I open a directory in File Explorer.
2. I try to delete this same directory (from a script or command line or whatever).
3. It fails to delete it because it's currently "in use" or "opened".

I would like for it to be deleted anyway, and visually closed (since it no longer exists), rather than getting the error.

At first, I thought that I should check if the dir can be "written to" and only delete it if so, but this will only stop the error from being logged; it won't actually solve the issue of deleting the directory.

Is this somehow possible to "force"? I can't think of many situations when I would want an opened dir in a GUI window to "block" the deletion of that same dir, and it keeps causing annoying issues for me as I'm developing.

Comment: Some delete methods allow force deleting. But the best way is to close the file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Explorer has a `FindFirstChangeNotification`/`FindNextChangeNotification` on the folder so it can update the contents of the folder if they change.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
rem :: open current foder in explorer ::
explorer .

rem :: kill explorer windows by title/path ::
2>nul >nul %__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /fi "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" /fi "windowtitle eq %CD%"

rem :: removing your folder \name :: 
if %errorlevel% == 0 for /d %%i in (.)do cd.. && rmdir "%%~nxi" /q /s
```